# Recursively iterate through nested list

Tags: java, list, algorithm, recursion

I want to implement a recursive function, which iterates through a sublist of an object within a list and add all of the elements in the sublists into a grand list.

My object is as follows:

List<Task> tasks with a function called .getDependsOn() which returns a List<Task> of which it depends.

From the beginning of a Task, which depends on Task B, which then again depends on Task C and D, I want to recursively iterate through every Task and add them to a big list, which includes EVERY dependent tasks of Task A.

```
public List<Task> addDependencies(List<Task> tasks) {
  for (Task task: tasks) {
   if (!task.getDependsOn().isEmpty()) {
    tasks.addAll(addDependencies(task.getDependsOn()));
    return tasks;
   } else {
    return tasks;
   }
  }
  return tasks;
}
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work, as it throws an InvocationTargetException. I am trying to solve my issue, try to debug it in my brain for like 2 hours now already, but can't sort it out.

Comment: It seems you have mixed up your input list and your output list, since your method takes an input parameter, modifies it and returns the same reference, which is simply redundant. Do you want to modify the original list or do you want to provide the result in a new list?

Comment: 1. Please provide the full stacktrace of *InvocationTargetException*, 2. Please add an example to reproduce the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems in your method:

1. You just return the `tasks` when `task.getDependsOn()` is empty, which ignore remaining `task` dependencies, you should call `continue` instead.
2. You didn't make a copy when you call `addDependencies(task.getDependsOn())`, which create unexpected side effect(changing `task.getDependsOn()`).

---

I prefer using Stream with [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) for this problem, since it will not create side effect, and we don't need to create many copy of List.

```java
public static Stream<Task> flattenDependencies(List<Task> tasks) {
    return tasks.stream().flatMap(task -> {
        Stream<Task> flattened = flattenDependencies(task.getDependsOn());
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(task), flattened);
    });
}
```

---

Full example
*Main class*

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FlattenTask {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Task a = new Task("a");
        Task b = new Task("b");
        Task c = new Task("c");
        Task d = new Task("d");
        Task e = new Task("e");
        Task f = new Task("f");
        a.setDependsOn(List.of(b, c));
        b.setDependsOn(List.of(d, e));
        List<Task> tasks = List.of(a, f);
        System.out.println(flattenDependencies(tasks).collect(Collectors.toList()).toString());
    }

    public static Stream<Task> flattenDependencies(List<Task> tasks) {
        return tasks.stream().flatMap(task -> {
            Stream<Task> flattened = flattenDependencies(task.getDependsOn());
            return Stream.concat(Stream.of(task), flattened);
        });
    }
}
```

*Task*

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Task {

    private final String code;
    private List<Task> dependsOn = Collections.emptyList();

    public Task(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public List<Task> getDependsOn() {
        return dependsOn;
    }

    public void setDependsOn(List<Task> dependsOn) {
        this.dependsOn = dependsOn;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exceptionally great response. Do you have any sources to train my algorithm skills (especially on recursion) other than the standard hackerrank competitions?

Answer (score 1):

I think your exception is happening because you're trying to append the list concurrently whilst iterating over it. If I've understood what you're trying to do, maybe something like this would work

```
public List<Task> addDependencies(List<Task> tasks) {
  List<Task> subTaskList = new ArrayList<Task>;
  for (Task task: tasks) {
   if (!task.getDependsOn().isEmpty())
    subTaskList.addAll(addDependencies(task.getDependsOn()));
  }
  tasks.addAll(subTaskList);
  return tasks;
}
```